# Maximin optimization

Tags: optimization

So I have the following optimization problem.

$$\max_{x\in C} \min(f^{\top}x,g^{\top}x)$$

Here $C$ is some bounded constraint set defined by linear inequalities only.

Suppose that $z^{*} = \max_{x\in C} \min(f^{\top}x,g^{\top}x)$. Let $x^{*}\in C$ denote an optimal solution. I was wondering under which conditions the following is true.
$$z^{*} = f^{\top}x^{*} = g^{\top}x^{*} \qquad (\triangle)$$

> > Non-example $1$: $C = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$, $f = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $g = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$.
> >
> > Non-example $2$: $C = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x \leq \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}\}$, $f = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $g = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$
> >
> > Example $1$: $C = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x \leq 1\}$, $f = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $g = \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix}$

Based on these toy examples, I get the feeling that at least one component of $f$ and $g$ should be opposite signed for $(\triangle)$ to be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is an answer to a special case of the problem in question due to the discussion in the comments:**

We consider
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
\max \quad \min(f^T x, g^T x) \quad\text{s.t.}\quad x \ge 0, e^T x = 1.
\end{align}

Using the KKT conditions or Lagrangian multiplier techniques, you will get a characterization:

We can rewrite the problem equivalently to
$$ 
\tag{2}
\max \{ z \mid  z \le f^T x, z \le g^T x, x \ge 0, e^T x = 1 \}, 
$$
which is a convex problem. That is, the KKT conditions are sufficient and necessary. They are
$$ \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -f \end{bmatrix} \lambda + \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -g \end{bmatrix} \mu + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -I \end{bmatrix} \nu + \begin{bmatrix}0\\ e\end{bmatrix}\rho = 0, $$
$$ z - f^T x \le 0, z - g^T x \le 0, -x \le 0, e^T x - 1 = 0$$
$$ \lambda, \mu, \nu \ge 0, $$
$$ \lambda(z - f^T x) = 0,  \mu(z - g^T x) = 0, \nu^T x = 0. $$
Simplify and adding the fact that $f^T x = g^T x$, we obtain
$$ \nu = \rho e - \lambda f - (1-\lambda) g, $$
$$ (f-g)^T x = 0, x \ge 0, e^T x = 1, $$
$$ \lambda \in[0,1], \nu \ge 0, $$
$$ \nu^T x = 0. $$
Using $\nu^T x = 0$ and $e^T x = 1$, we obtain
$$ \rho = f^T x. $$
That is, we obtain following sufficient condition for a maximizer of (1):
$$ f^T x e - \lambda f - (1-\lambda) g \ge 0, $$
$$ (f-g)^T x = 0, e^T x = 1, x \ge 0, \lambda\in [0, 1]. $$

**A non example:**

Consider
$$ C = [0, 1]^2 $$ and
$$ f = \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad g = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}. $$
Then, for $x\in C$ we have
$$ \min(f^T x, g^T x) = \min(-x_1, x_2) = -x_1, $$
hence
$$ z^* = \max_{x\in C} \min(f^T x, g^T x) = \max_{x_1 \in [0,1]} -x_1 = 0. $$
Now, the set of maximizers is
$$ X^* = \{ (0, x_2) \mid x_2 \in [0,1] \}. $$
So, for any $x^*\in X^*\setminus \{ 0 \}$ we have
$$ z^* = f^T x^* = 0 < g^T x^*. $$

Comment: Thanks. I still think there should be some interesting cases for which my claim is true but I need to sharpen my intuition further.

Comment: I said it is a non-example because my claim is not true in that case. From the two non-examples and the one example I got the feeling that the required condition must be that the vectors $f$ and $g$ should have opposite signs somewhere. You invalidated that with your answer. So now I am wondering if uniqueness AND opposite signs are sufficient to make my claim true.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @Calculon: I added an characterization.

Comment: Thank you. I will wait a bit before approving your answer. Hopefully someone will propose a more intuitive characterization.

Comment: @Calculon in fact, I am also hoping for it.  That result is rather not enlighten :(

Comment: We are just looking for conditions under which the inequalities $z \leq f^{\top}x$ and $z \leq g^{\top}x$ are active. It has been a while since I studied linear programming but there should be some way of determining this without actually solving an lp.

Comment: @Calculon: without knowing the geometry of $C$, I doubt.

Comment: Actually I do know what $C$ is. 
$$C = \{x: 0 \leq x \leq l, x^{\top}\vec 1 = 1, Ax = b \}$$

Here $A$ contains only $1$s and $0$s Does this help?

Comment: @Calculon: you could plug that into the kkt conditions. I haven't  seen anything obvious directly.

Comment: If $C = \{x : x \geq 0, x^{\top}\vec 1 = 1\}$, I still get equality in my data set.    Do we then get "nice" conditions on $f$ and $g$ for equality to hold?

Comment: @Calculon: I updated the answer. It is little bit nicer, but not much.